# Viewing Linux File Permission Number

Tags: linux

So I know that ls -l directory will get you the file permssion on a directory...and I know that chmod number directory will change the file permissions on a directory.

But how can I view the number translation of a file permission? I'd like to make an exact copy of a file permission, without making a mistake (I figured it's easy to mess up a number translation of a file permission)

Thanks

(PS I need the number for drwxr-xr-x)

Comment: Why do not simply use `stat()` call. It would put file permissions into `stat.st_mode` field as integer.

Answer (score 2):

Its just a bit field so its 421 421 421 add up the 
                            rwx rwx rwx 
so in your case

```
   421
   rwx = 7
   r x = 5
   r x = 5

   755
```

Comment: Thanks,....I think i'm not doing the command right....is it just chmod 755 directory?

Or is there something else

Comment: The full syntax for `chmod` is 4 digits. For normal files/folders, the leading digit is `0`. (e.g. `chmod 0755 somefile.txt`). Note, `chmod` will work with 3 digits, but be aware of the 4th.

Comment: what is it you are expecting to see that you are not when running the command?  You can add a -R to it to have it recurse through the directory and chmod everything but that is generally a bad idea.